# Completely clean previous Radeon drivers on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: windows-7, drivers, amd-radeon

Recently I replaced my old Radeon HD 2600XT to Radeon HD 6770 from MSI.

I had strange problem that after installing the newest Radeon drivers they exist only until first reboot. After reboot my new card is recognized as an old 2600.

I tried to unintall ATI/AMD software completetely from Programs/Features, then reboot, then untinstall driver from device manager, then reboot, then system showed that display driver is regular VGA (and oldschool 640x480 resolutions). Then to be double sure I executed DriverCleaner3 and Driver sweeper. After the restart I installed the newest drivers from amd site but after restarting the system recognizes card as 2600.

I'm completely lost. Perhaps Win7 64bit caches somewhere drivers? Are there any issues regarding drivers-shadowing or 32/64 mirroring?

Reinstalling the system is not an option.

Comment: You could try and run ccleaner http://www.piriform.com/ccleaner

Comment: Or unistall it with: http://www.freenew.net/windows/iobit-uninstaller-2-0/68873.htm

Comment: You SURE you didn't put the 2600 back in (have to ask)?  Have you tried manually assigning the drivers to the card after it's detected as a 2600?

Comment: Best video driver cleaner there is...http://www.drivercleaner.net/

Comment: Yes I'm sure that newer card is inside.

Answer (score 1):

- Download Driver Sweeper from - http://phyxion.net/item/driver-sweeper.html
- Install DriverSweeper
- Uninstall your Radeon drivers from the Control Panel > Programs and Features
- Reboot your system into safe mode (Hit <kbd>F8</kbd> during Boot)
- Run DriverSweeper (from within Windows Safe Mode)
- Check on "AMD-Display"
- Hit Analyze
- Select All and Hit "Clean"
- Reboot back into Normal Windows (not safe mode)
- Install your new drivers

Comment: Looks like Driver Sweeper is now Driver Fusion. The current link points to a redirect to this link: http://treexy.com/products/driver-fusion

Comment: Driver Sweeper got replaced by Driver Fusion. The free version doesn't have all the features. I tried to use it and it said it couldn't completely clean all of the files and to purchase the premium version (~$20). But you can find the old version of Driver Sweeper for free and it looks like it does not have its features limited. I downloaded and ran it after running Driver Fusion and it found a bunch of registry keys. http://www.techspot.com/downloads/4266-driver-sweeper.html