# Graphics card isn't performing as expected

Tags: graphics

I have just upgraded from a Sapphire AMD 6670 2 GB graphics card to a Nvidia GTX 650 TI 2 GB SSC and my Windows Experiance index has gone from 6.8 to 7.7. When playing games I am seeing no improvements: I cannot play Saints Row Three on even the lowest settings but according to many people and benchmarks on the web I should be able to play it comfortably.

I want to know why this is happening to me. I have installed the latest drivers and I have DirectX 10 and 11 installed.

I'm using a DVI cable, not HTML. Is it possible that this would affect performance?

PC specifications:

- 4100 Quad core processor 3.6 GHz
- 8 GB RAM
- 1 TB HDD
- 450W PSU

Also I was never able to ply saints row 3 thats why i upgraded because i couldnt play many games

Comment: Without more information about your computer configuration it's hard to diagnose this. Please edit your question with the full configuration of your PC.

However, with a change of GPU vendor drivers from the old vendor can be interfering with the new ones. Please take a look at http://superuser.com/questions/378121/completely-clean-previous-radeon-drivers-on-windows-7-64bit and follow the instructions in the answer on how to completely clean the old drivers.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "i cannot play saints row three"? Did it work with the old card? What are the **actual** problems you're experiencing. And, no, the type of cable you use will not have an impact on your performance.

Comment: "I'm using a DVI cable, not HTML." I think you mean not VGA. In any case this would not affect performance.

Answer (score 3):

Try running other games to see if you still get a lousy experience. If so, chances are your card is faulty, go change it. Else, chances are the game files are corrupted and you just reinstall that game. Or if you're unlucky, the current drivers have a bug and messes up that game.

Also no, DVI doesn't affect your performance.